# How do I take the image view from one activity and set it as the background for another?

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I have two pages in my Android application, and I would like to set the background of the first page to be the image displayed in an Image View on the second page. How can I achieve this programmatically?
I have been trying to set the background of the second page in my Android application to be the image displayed in an Image View on the first page. I have made an attempt at achieving this, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Can someone please review my code and provide guidance on how to properly do it?

first activity from where the image view is taken

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.Graphics;

using SQLite;

namespace HAMANIA_APP
{
    [Activity(Label = "GallerySaver")]
    public class GallerySaver : Activity
    {
        Button camera, save, uploadPhoto;
        ImageView pic;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        bool mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
        bool mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        public static readonly int imageid = 1000;

        

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Phone_Gallery_Saver);
            camera = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
            save = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSave);
            pic = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.gallery);
            save.Click += Save_Click;
            camera.Click += Camera_Click;
            


            // Create your application here
        }

        

        private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent inte = new Intent();
            inte.SetType("image/*");
            inte.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(inte, "Select Picture"), imageid);

            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Image saved to gallery", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        private void Camera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 0)//coming from camera
            {
                if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
                {
                    Bundle extras = data.Extras;
                    bitmap = (Bitmap)extras.Get("data");
                    pic.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    //bitmap = (Android.Graphics.Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
                    // pic.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    
                }
                
                }else
                {
                    if ((requestCode == imageid) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
                    {
                        Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, uri);
                        pic.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    var image = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");

                    

                }
            }
        }

        
    }
}
```

the second page for the background to be set in

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Android.Provider;
using Java.IO;
using System.IO;
using Android.Net;
using AndroidX.Core.Content;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;

namespace HAMANIA_APP
{
    [Activity(Label = "MenuActivity")]
    public class MenuActivity : Activity
    {
        Button camera, gallery, control;
        BroadcastBattery broadcastBattery;
        TextView tv;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Menu);
            camera = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BLUETOOTH);
            tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
            broadcastBattery = new BroadcastBattery(tv);
            control = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.control);
            control.Click += Control_Click;
            gallery = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.gallery);
            camera.Click += Camera_Click;
           
        }

        public static string BackgroundImagePath { get; set; }


        private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ControlCenter));
            StartActivity(intent);
        }

        private void Camera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, typeof(GallerySaver));
            StartActivity(intent2);
        }

        
    }
}
```

I appreciate the help

Comment: your question is a bit of confusing, do you want to: `I would like to set the background of the first page to be the image displayed in an Image View on the second page`? 

Or 

`set the background of the second page in my Android application to be the image displayed in an Image View on the first page`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert bitmap into byte array and pass it back to `MenuActivity`  by  `Intent`.

Based on your code, I created a demo and achieved this function.And it works properly on my side.

You can refer to the following code:

**MenuActivity.cs**

In order to receive data from activity `GallerySaver`,I replaced code `StartActivity(intent2);` with `StartActivityForResult`   method `Camera_Click`：

```
  Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, typeof(GallerySaver));
  //StartActivity(intent2);

  StartActivityForResult (intent2, 0);
```

And override method `OnActivityResult`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public class MenuActivity : Activity
{
    Button camera, gallery, control;
    //BroadcastBattery broadcastBattery;
    TextView tv;


    LinearLayout rootlayout;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Menu);

        camera = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BLUETOOTH);
        tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
        //broadcastBattery = new BroadcastBattery(tv);
        //control = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.control);
        //control.Click += Control_Click;
        gallery = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.gallery);
        camera.Click += Camera_Click;
         
       //rootlayout is the root layout of this activity
        rootlayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.rootlayout);    
    }


    private void Camera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, typeof(GallerySaver));
        //StartActivity(intent2);

        StartActivityForResult (intent2, 0);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            // Get image from intent as ByteArray
            var image = data.GetByteArrayExtra("picture");
            if (image != null)
            {
                //Convert byte array back into bitmap
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(image, 0, image.Length);

                BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);

                 // set Background for this activity
                rootlayout.Background = drawable;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**GallerySaver.cs**

After capturing picture, you can convert bitmap into byte array and pass it back by intent and call `SetResult`.

```
     //convert bitmap into byte array
                    byte[] bitmapData;
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                        bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
                    }

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.PutExtra("picture", bitmapData);

                    SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
                    Finish();
```

The whole code of `GallerySaver.cs`:

```
   [Activity(Label = "GallerySaver")] 
    public class GallerySaver : Activity
    {
        Button camera, save, uploadPhoto;
        ImageView pic;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        public static readonly int imageid = 1000;

        Intent intent;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Phone_Gallery_Saver);


            camera = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamera);
            save = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSave);
            pic = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.gallery);
            save.Click += Save_Click;
            camera.Click += Camera_Click;
        }

        private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent inte = new Intent();
            inte.SetType("image/*");
            inte.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(inte, "Select Picture"), imageid);

            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Image saved to gallery", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        private void Camera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        [Obsolete]
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 0)//coming from camera
            {
                if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
                {
                    Bundle extras = data.Extras;
                    bitmap = (Bitmap)extras.Get("data");
                    pic.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    //convert bitmap into byte array
                    byte[] bitmapData;
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                        bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
                    }

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.PutExtra("picture", bitmapData);

                    SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
                    Finish();

                }

            }
            else
            {
                if ((requestCode == imageid) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
                {
                    Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, uri);
                    pic.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    var image = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");

                    // you also use SetResult to achieve this.
                }
            }
        }

    }
```